# Python caching in for loop

Tags: python, caching

I recently came across the following behaviour which surprised me, which I first thought was due to Python's small integer caching.

#### Integer caching

```py
id(0)
id(0) # Same as above
```

These two match, as expected from small integer caching.

#### Integer caching

```py
id(123456789)
id(123456789) # These differ
```

These differ, as I would expect.

#### What is going on here?

```py
list((id(123456789) for i in range(2)) # These are the same!
[id(123456789) for i in range(2)] # These are the same, but different from the previous. 
for i in range(2): print(id(123456789)) # These are the same, but different from the previous. 
for i in range(2): print(id(123456789)) # These are the same, but different from the previous.
```

It seems some caching is going on when the variables are in a for loop. I wasn't expecting this, and would be keen to be pointed in the right direction for an explanation. I am battling an issue where I want the `ids()` of elements to be different, but this caching is getting in my way.

Comment: "would be keen to be pointed in the right direction for an explanation." python will cache immutable literals in a code block. So, do something like `def foo():` and inside, do `x = 1337` and `y = 1337` then `print(id(x), id(y))` and they will be the same. This is an implementation detail. But again, the real issue here is that you are "I am battling an issue where I want the ids() of elements to be different, but this caching is getting in my way." What exactly are you doing? Why would you ever care about the ids of `int` objects?

Comment: `# These differ` you are probably doing this in a REPL, where each expression/statement is its own block.

Comment: https://github.com/satwikkansal/wtfPython#-how-not-to-use-is-operator

Answer (score 0):

okay so let me explain what is happening in caching, the caching mechanism is used for fast retrival for the data, so that it doesn't be calculated again.
However, it depends on not only that value "in that case the int" but also on the type of where is these integers saved in.

take the first case :

```
list((id(123456789) for i in range(2)) # These are the same!
```

here you use a list type, but not a fast type the ABC defined type object, in that case the allocation for the cache will be different than the second case :

```
[id(123456789) for i in range(2)] # These are the same, but different from the previous.
```

where you use a list type that is compiled directly through the interpreter, which means there is no object to be reserved in the memory, which results a different in caching allocations.

the third and fourth case are the same but they're tricky, the reason for that is that they'll never be the same, every integer in python above 100 "for my knowledge" have a different cache allocation, and the reason!! I don't think that anyone knows for certain why specifically 100, but what has been told and mentioned in Python3 Docs that it's because they're the most used numpers between the others, so it won't be logical to recompile them over and over.

after this small talk about why the caching mechanism is so weird, let me see your problem from another prespective by answering the opposite of that question, the only case for two elements to have the same `id()` is because they're the same object, as long as their lifecycles don't overlap. otherwise it'll always be different.

thanks for @slothrop for noticing this.

Comment: *"the only case for two elements to have the same ids() is because they're the same object"* It's possible for two different objects to have the same id(), as long as their lifecycles don't overlap. (As @tdelaney says in a comment, if you create and destroy an object, then the next object you create might just happen to have the same id().)

Comment: yes you're Right, it was my problem not to declare this point while talking about the concept of "having the same id()", thanks for the edit @slothrop .